# Grails select won't display string from nested class

Tags: grails

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, that apparently is not that simple. I have a domain class:

```
class Regex {
    String name
    String Regex 
}
```

and another class:

```
class RegexRef {
    int sequenceNumber
    Product product
    Regex regex
}
```

Now, in a select, I want to list the RegexRef instances, with the name of the regex as the optionValue as such:

```
<g:select name="regexRef.id" from="${com.mycompany.RegexRef.list()}" optionKey="id" size="5" optionValue="regex.name" value="${actionRefInstance?.regexRef?.id}"  />
```

but this doesn't work. It throws:
Exception Message: No such property: regex.name for class: com.jetheaddev.RegexRef

I can do this mis-direction in other constructs...

```
<g:link controller="regexRef" action="show" id="${actionRefInstance?.regexRef?.id}">${actionRefInstance?.regexRef?.regex.name.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link>
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `optionValue="regex.name"` the `<g:select/>` is trying to retrieve the property of RegexRef as:

```
regexRefInstance."regex.name"
```

To retrieve the name property on the `Regex` class do:

```
<g:select optionValue="${{it.regex.name}}"/>
```

which will run the optionValue `Closure` on each entry in the list and retrieve the related `name` property.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Where does one find out about that it variable, which I'm assuming is the placeholder object for the select list entries?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking, but in the documentation on [g:select](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) the `optionKey` description mentions that it is a property on the bean, which are the individual entities of your `.list()`.  Further down in the examples there is one showing the `optionValue` `Closure` answer I've given you.